# SharePoint Page Library Permission Setting

Tags: permissions, groups, publishing-page

I have a question regarding SharePoint permission on Pages Library.
Lets say I have a User Group A (contribute) with userA and userB in the group,
how can I make the metadatas of the page is viewable by userA and some other metadatas is  viewable by userB?
is it possible to set permission on Content Type level?

please advice. thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

No, permissions can't be set on a content type level, and it sounds like you want column level permissions within the list. Unfortunately, this is also not possible.

What you could try is using an [SPSecurityTrimmedControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx) to hide different bits of the page from different users (provided they do actually *have* different permissions) - but they'd still be able to see the different columns of metadata if they went to the Page Library itself, or the View form.

Comment: Hi Andy Burns, thank you for your reply. Due to the requirements constraint, I have to put users into same group, but wanted to have column level permission to the users (users all same permission). Any workaround on this? perhaps custom code (.aspx or .ascx) can achieve this.